# ZfcUserDoctrineMongoODM Configuration examples

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am trying to configure ZendFramwork 2 to use MongoDB as the storage for user Authentication.

I already have installed what I believe are the correct modules and have a correctly installed instance of ZF2 running on Nginx. I also have an instance of Mongo running and I am already using this for another project. The modules declaration in application.config.php looks like this

'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
        'ZfcUserDoctrineMongoODM',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineMongoODMModule'
    )

Documentation is a bit thin on how to configure the system to get it working. Can anyone provide any code fragments around configuring the database settings to allow Mongo to run with ZfcUser, this is where I am at a loss now.

Any help, clues or cheat sheets would be greatly appreciated.

Darren Breeze

Comment: I suppose doctrine modules must be above Zfc modules. What is the error you got? Are you able to access page `/user/register` ?

Comment: The gap I have is the configuration for the database user collection. I can access the login pages from ZfcUser, but there of course is no database behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Doctrine Mongo ODM module readme https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule :

> copy
>   vendor/doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module/config/module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php.dist
>   into your application's config/autoload directory, rename it to
>   module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php and make the appropriate changes.
>   With this config file you can configure your mongo connection, add
>   extra annotations to register, add subscribers to the event manager,
>   add filters to the filter collection, and drivers to the driver chain.

So you have something like this at your autoload config:

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(

        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server'           => 'localhost',
                'port'             => '27017',
//                'connectionString' => null,
//                'user'             => null,
//                'password'         => null,
//                'dbname'           => null,
//                'options'          => array()
            ),
        ),
....
'configuration' => array(
        'odm_default' => array(
         ... 'default_db'         => 'myappdb',
        )
)
```

So tune it and try to register at `user/register`. Collection name is `user` by default.

Comment: That looks like the ticket, will try in the morning and report back. Thank you!

Comment: It was that simple in the end, I have now registered, have the data appearing in Mongdb and can authenticate. Thanks for your help. All I did was follow the instructions at the top, set the server to the server IP address and set the default_db to user.

Comment: Sorry I cant yet, as a newbee to this site I am short of reputation points.